# Can you 'break' from a Context Manager?

Tags: python, control-flow, contextmanager

Is there any pattern that allows you to exit from a Context Manager and return the control flow to the code following the `with (...):`?

For example (doesn't actually work):

```
with open('/etc/passwd', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(0, 2)
    if f.tell() < 10:
        print "The file is too small!"
        break

    # Process the file.
```

Is there anything I can replace `break` with to do the same thing?

Comment: Your example sounds like you want to use exceptions instead.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `if f.tell() >= 10: do stuff else: "file is too small"` here?

Comment: This is what exceptions are *for*.

Answer (score 1):

it doesnt look like you can exit from `with` but you can wrap it in a loop so you can exit - eg like so

```
for _ in [0]:
    with open('/etc/passwd', 'r') as f:
        f.seek(0, 2)
        if f.tell() < 10:
            print "The file is too small!"
            break
```

but propably using exceptions (like mentioned in the comments) or wrapping in a function and `return`ing (I would prefer `return`ing) is more natural.